# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader (CORS)

Tags: php, api, cors

I am integrating Pay360 hosted cashier API and getting redirect URL in response from API. When i redirect user to URL, getting CORS error. code is as below:

```
$post = array(
    "session" => array(
                    "returnUrl" => array("url" => "https://www.holidayfactory.co.uk/test"),
                    "transactionNotification" => array("url" => "https://www.holidayfactory.co.uk/test",
                                                    "format" => "REST_JSON")
                ),
    "transaction" => array("merchantReference" => "123131",
                            "money" => array("amount" => array("fixed" => "80.00"),
                                            "currency" => "GBP"
                                        )
                    ),
    "customer" => array("registered" => false,
                        "details" => array(
                                        "name" => "name",
                                        "address" => array("line1" => "address",
                                                            "line2" => "address",
                                                            "city" => "address",
                                                            "region" => "address",
                                                            "postcode" => "address",
                                                            "countryCode" => "GBR"),
                                        "telephone" => "1235465",
                                        "emailAddress" => "email@email.com",
                                        "ipAddress" => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                                        "defaultCurrency" => "GBP"
                                    )
                    )
);

$instid =****; // Hosted Cashier Installation ID
$u = "*************"; // API Username
$p = "*************"; // API Password

$host = "https://api.mite.pay360.com"; // Test

$ch = curl_init("$host/hosted/rest/sessions/$instid/payments");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$u:$p");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($response);
if($obj->redirectUrl){
    header("Location:$obj->redirectUrl");
    die;
    }
```

i have searched google for solution and after a long time of research i found that headers should be added to .htaccess file. so i have added below code to .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

but the problem still not resolved. can anyone help me?

Thanks